# Member Procedure / Member Function / Type of the Oracle to PG

Tags: postgresql

Member procedure and member function and types from the Oracle into PostgreSQL.

ORACLE CODE:

```
create or replace TYPE    "TEST_ACC"     AS OBJECT(
OGID        VARCHAR2(6),
ACCT           VARCHAR2(10),
member procedure TEST_ACC_I (ADT IN VARCHAR2),
member function TEST_ACC_II RETURN VARCHAR2
);



create or replace TYPE BODY               "TEST_ACC" AS
MEMBER PROCEDURE TEST_ACC_I(ADT IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
OGID        :=RPAD(trim(replace(replace(SUBSTR(ADT, 1,6),CHR(9),''),chr(13),'')), 6, ' ');
ACCT          := RPAD(trim(replace(replace(SUBSTR(ADT,  7,10),CHR(9),''),chr(13),'')), 10, ' ');
END;
MEMBER FUNCTION TEST_ACC_II
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
RETURN RPAD(trim(replace(replace(OGID, chr(9), ''),chr(13),'')), 6, ' ') ||
       RPAD(trim(replace(replace(ACCT, chr(9), ''),chr(13),'')), 10, ' ') ||
      
END;
END;


ORA CODE: Using in the other procedure.

v_t_acc := TEST_ACC(null, null, null, null);
```

Postgresql:

I've tried to create a type:

```
CREATE TYPE abc.TEST_ACC AS
(
    OGID character varying(6),
    ACCT character varying(10),
    
);
```

Tried to create a separate procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc.assign_test_acc(
    adt character varying)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

Declare
    OGID character varying(6);
    ACCT character varying(10);
    BEGIN
OGID        :=RPAD(trim(replace(replace(SUBSTRING(STR, 1,6),CHR(9),''),chr(13),'')), 6, ' ');
ACCT          := RPAD(trim(replace(replace(SUBSTRING(STR,  7,10),CHR(9),''),chr(13),'')), 10, ' ');

END;
$BODY$;
```

I'm not getting how do i call the procedure for this `v_t_acc := TEST_ACC(null, null, null, null)` in postgresql.  I'm not sure about the whole process.

Comment: A procedure doesn't return anything. You need a function that returns a value of type `test_acc`

Comment: @_a_horse_with_no_name   #1: Member procedure/function associated with that test_acc TYPE.

#2:  v_t_acc := TEST_ACC(null, null, null, null);

In another procedure, the above code is used in an Oracle.

What can I do for PostgreSQL? Please, provide any reference/Sample.

Comment: You'll have to rethink and rewrite it. There are no "object types" with constructors in PostgreSQL, so don't try to go that way.

Comment: Any sample code/ reference please. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Sorry, there is no sample code or reference. You will have to think yourself: what does the current code do? Are there other ways to achieve the same goal? Read the PL/pgSQL documentation.